# Ubuntu 12 - how to install Ruby and Rails correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-12.04

I read a lot of articles regarding installing `Ruby 1.9` and Ruby on `Rails 3.2.3` on `Ubuntu 12`. And I've installed them previously. But it took much time, about 5 days. I made many mistakes and I was very tired of that.

Now I need to do it again. Obviously I want it to be effortless and correct. Like in Windows using Rails installer and Ruby installer.

Can anyone give me a link about how to install them correctly(!)? Or maybe you know the right way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Follow this and enjoy

[Install Ruby and Rails completely with chruby](http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you//)

Comment: How do I install `libmysqlclient-dev package` for mysql  or `libpq-dev` for postgresql? I didn't find the command how to do that in the article you gave me.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libpg-dev

Answer (score 4):

I would use [RVM](https://rvm.io/). I found it super easy to install and it maintains different per-user (or system-wide if you wish) gemsets for different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer rvm for installation of ruby and rails.

Here some very useful articles which guide you how to install ruby, rails using rvm.

1) http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/21/set-up-an-ubuntu-local-development-machine-for-ruby-on-rails/

2) http://hivelogic.com/articles/setup-guide-rails-stack-with-passenger-rvm-bundler-apache-and-mysql-on-ubun/