# Error while installing rails `$ gem install rails`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi I am new to Ruby on Rails and trying to setup in my machine [Ububntu 12.04 LTS]. I successfully installed `Ruby` and `Gem` now I am getting error while installing `Rails`
Here is my version of `Ruby` and `Gem`

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
2.1.7
```

Now when I try command `$ sudo gem install rails` or `$ gem install rails`

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I looked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19151697/2450409) and updated the ca-certificate using `$ sudo update-ca-certificates` but it is still not working?

Help me as I new to `RoR` I have no idea what to do next since I have applied all measures I could. Thank you in advanced.

**EDIT:** Suggest me a way I can solve this problem, incase I don't find one I will be doing   it using RVM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391679/ubuntu-12-how-to-install-ruby-and-rails-correctly

Comment: try changing in gemfile https rubygems.org to http rubygems.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)

Answer (score 3):

Some packages may b missing. Try this.

```
rvm get head
rvm requirements run
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3 --install --default
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and simply had to update RubyGems

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely rubygems.org is down temporarily, try running this command to add one of the mirrors as source

```
gem source -a 'https://production.cf.rubygems.org'
```

and then run

```
gem install rails
```

There are some more mirrors available.

Answer (score 0):

Without `ssl`:

```
$gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
```