# "gem install rails" fails with DNS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, rubygems

```
$ rvm use
Using /home/owner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 80 (http://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.4.gemspec.rz)
$ gem update --system
...
$ gem -v
2.4.1
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 80 (http://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.1.5.gemspec.rz)
```

I have attempted:

1. Installing other gems (devise, activerecord). I get the same error.
2. Reinstalling RVM
3. Running `gem update --system`
4. Setting static DNS to google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
5. Adding `https://production.cf.rubygems.org` as a gem source (see below for error)
6. Installing 14.04 over my previous 12.04. Error persists. The source of the error must be outside my computer.

### Additional information about my connection:

1. I can connect to `https://rubygems.org/` through my browser
2. My modem's firewall is completely disabled.
3. `$ curl -v --head https://rubygems.org` output:  http://pastebin.com/ca6DAvaU

### My /etc/resolv.conf

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.co
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 75.75.75.75
search home.network
```

### Add direct gem source

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299266/3993020

```
owner@owner-Z87X-UD3H:~$ gem sources --add https://production.cf.rubygems.org
Error fetching https://production.cf.rubygems.org:
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443 (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/specs.4.8.gz)
```

### Additional debug information for `gem install rails`

```
owner@owner-Z87X-UD3H:~$ gem install rails --debug -V
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `LoadError' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:169 - LoadError
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block
200 OK
Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:547 - _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org
Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879 - Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:286 - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443 (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.1.5.gemspec.rz)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443 (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.1.5.gemspec.rz)
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:286:in `rescue in fetch_path'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:259:in `fetch_path'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source.rb:146:in `fetch_spec'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/api_specification.rb:76:in `spec'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:77:in `add_always_install'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:461:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:238:in `install_gem'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:299:in `block in install_gems'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `each'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `install_gems'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:202:in `execute'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:307:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:168:in `process_args'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:138:in `run'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
    /home/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I should mention I'm able to browse the internet flawlessly. This question was posted from the same computer that generated the DNS error.

Comment: Wondering that where `"your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network"` message coming from. Post your Gemfile

Comment: there is no role of gemfile in installing rvm,ruby,rails

Comment: I just got this error too. Here I tried installing the Treat gem.

Comment: I just got "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" and when I googled it, it lead me here.  The big difference? I got it from Outlook which was asking me if I wanted to get redirected there to get new settings. Never seen it before.

Comment: Can you provide more details of your connection? is your browser capable of accessing https://rubygems.org? Is your system running behind a transparent proxy or some proxy firewall?

Comment: @LuisLavena I have updated my post to include the information you requested. How would I know if I'm behind a transparent proxy, or a proxy firewall?

Comment: @tmtmtmtmt can you run a `curl -v --head https://rubygems.org` and tell us how it resolves the IP/configuration?

Comment: @LuisLavena My output for running `curl -v --head https://rubygems.org`:  http://pastebin.com/ca6DAvaU

Comment: I was able to run `gem install rails` successfully after swapping out my Comcast modem for another. Any advice on further debugging to determine what the difference between the two is?

Comment: The your-dns-needs-immediate-attention message is from the ICANN. See https://icann.org/namec
ollision and https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/name-collision-mitigation-01aug14-en.pdf page 21

Answer (score 30):

Like **blasio** pointed out. It seems like the Xfinity modems are setting up the search domain to `home.network` and this is messing things up for the reasons he mentioned (essentially, home.network is now a valid domain name that the modems are trying to contact before making a connection).

I had the same problem and the modification on resolv.conf seem to do the trick, and that should probably be an accepted solution for linux environments. I had this problem while attempting this on a virtual machine running ubuntu, and my host(OSX Mavericks) was passing down the `search home.network` like the modem is, so I wanted to see if I could find a solution that could be done at the host OS level because the same problem happened when I attempted `gem install rails` on my OSX terminal.

If you go to the OSX network settings, under DNS you'll see the `home.network` line under the Search Domains area. After some googling it seems that comcast recently changed this from `http://hds1.ma.comcast.net'`. I changed it back, restarted and gave `gem install rails` another shot, which worked with no problem.

Strange issue but this is a better solution that swapping modems or changing gem sources.

Comment: What, exactly, did you change, where? The home.network search domain is greyed out in the DNS tab in Network Preferences, which means it's coming from somewhere else, right?

Comment: Thanks, after going wild trying all crazy different stuff this helped.

Comment: @tamouse, this is coming from your modem. You're essentially adding something down the hierarchy. So on the DNS tab, where you see home.network, you should see a plus sign to add a new search domain. Inter `http://hds1.ma.comcast.net` there and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, @jalvarado91. I actually added home.local, which is what it used to be at some point, and that works, for me. I don't think an `http://` URL is going to work in that field, though. DNS isn't using port 80 to search, as far as I know.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you for saving me hours of my life.

Comment: This solves the problem and also occurs when I'm behind a Comcast network. From my testing, it seems like both `http://hds1.ma.comcast.net` and `hds1.ma.comcast.net` work when added to the search domains section under **DNS**, in the _Network_ preference pane.

Comment: This fixed it! What a strange combination of things going wrong.

Comment: Thanks that helped. For OSX I had to reconnect to the network to apply the search domain change.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with Comcast xFinity and Compass.

Update for Windows 7 users:

```
Go to Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center
Under "Active Networks" select "Connections: Local Area Connections"
In the "Local Area Connection Status" dialogue box, click on "Properties"
Double click the IPv4 item
In the "Internet Proptocol Verion 4" icon or click the "Properties" button, then click "Advanced"
In the DNS tab, just above the 2nd input box, click the "Append These DNS suffixes (in order)" radio button,
    then click "Add", enter "home.lan", then click OK until the dialogue closes.

    Many thanks to John Smith for the Vista fix and Somnambulent for Win 8.1 fix.
```

Answer (score 5):

Your DNS error seems to be related to .network becoming a [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) and your resolv.conf missing the [ndots](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-dns-search-list-for-host-name-lookup/) configuration. I just run into this issue with .prod.

Unless you have your own DNS server at home for internal .network domain, removing the `search home.network` from /etc/resolv.conf should fix the issue.

Since your /etc/resolv.conf is generated by resolveconf as it says in your resolv.conf, you might want to remove the home.network from your configuration, see [here for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot)

Answer (score 4):

I just want to say thank you to you all. Since I'm new here. I cannot add a comment even vote up. So I can only come to the answer part.

I got a problem as follow when I tried to install cocoapods:

```
➜  ~  gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443 (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-0.33.1.gemspec.rz)`enter code here`
```

Adding `home.local` into the DNS Search Domains fixes it.

Thanks again! I admire your spirit!!!

Comment: Are you saying that adding `home.local` is actually a viable solution to the question?  Otherwise this should be closed as "Not An Answer".

Comment: Yes, adding home.local is a viable solution to the question!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using RVM (1.25.29), Ubuntu 14.04 and ruby 2.0.0. This was a fresh RVM and ruby 2.0 installation.

In my case I was trying to install OpenShift Online's command-line tool: rhc with "gem install rhc".

I finally fixed it by using *bundle install* and a Gemfile. I'm not sure why but *bundle* was able to get the gems via **https** to rubygems.org, but "gem install" could not.

### Try creating a Gemfile with your gem in it as a temporary fix to get the gem installed.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# have bundle handle the gem install via https
gem 'rails'
```

Then run:

```
 bundle install
```

The only way I was able to get it to work using "gem install" was to use:

```
gem install --source http://rubygems.org
```

**But that's unsafe and NOT recommended.**

I haven't been able to determine why *bundle* can install via **https**, but gem can't. I'm relatively new to ruby and rvm.

The *bundler* gem came with the **rvm** installation, but **rubygems** came with ruby2.0.0-p481. At first and because of the error I thought it had something to do with openssl, but after a lot of trial and error it seems to be related to missing, dependent gems.

After the gem was installed via *bundle*, I was able to uninstall it and then re-install via "gem install". I noticed that "bundle install" installed some missing network and ssl-related gems before installing "rhc".

Without knowing a whole lot about how *bundle* and *gem install* work I'm thinking that the *bundler* gem had "everything" it needed to go out via **https** while *rubygems* (which came with the ruby 2.0 install) didn't. And that would explain why after the **bundle install**, *gem install* worked.

I hope this works for anyone else that's encountered this. If not, at least it's one more thing to try ;-).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using openSUSE 13.1 OS for my rails development. Suddenly I got the same issue and reported to the SUSE [mailing list](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2015-03/msg00620.html). And then got an very good explanation about the problem [here](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2015-03/msg00621.html).

> Background: the tld ".site" is offically registered and thus no longer available for private use.
>
> ToDo: Change your private tld, to something NOT registered.
>
> Gotchas: ".local" is reserved for mDNS / ZeroConf / Bonjour / Rendezvous.
>   Do NOT use it for DNS / DHCP !
>
> Examples:
>   ".box", ".lan" : both are suggested by some Internet-Connect-Routers 
>   (DSL/Cable/Fibre)
>   ".lnet", ".your-name-here" (.ArupRakshit for you) : possible, worth to try.
>
> HTH, Yamaban.

I followed his instrutions [here](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2015-03/msg00624.html)

> For future reader goto YAST -> Netwrok devices -> Network Settings -> 
>   Hostname/DNS -> Domain Name (and here put your name).

```
[arup@Rails]$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2 


Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%) 
........
........
[arup@Rails]$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.0
```

Now all  is set. :)

Answer (score 2):

New top level domains - .prod, .network are real domains not be be used as internal placeholder - https://icann.org/namecollision

Answer (score 1):

For me **"your-dns-needs-immediate-attention"**, actually meant "your gem sources are not valid".

```
gem source --list
```

Check the output. If the current list isn't valid, then you can simply

```
gem source -a https://rubygems.org
```

...or whatever other sources are appropriate. Then use the `-r` flag to remove the invalid sources.

Answer (score 0):

it appears comcast recently appended home.network to customers DNS search path

I resolved this issue by completing the following steps on Windows Vista:

control panel -> network and sharing center -> manage network connections -> wireless properties -> ip4 properties -> advanced -> dns tab -> select append these dns suffices in order and added home.lan.

now gem install runs without a hitch

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if anyone's encountering this in Windows, here's how I fixed it (in 8.1).

1. Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center
2. Click into your network adaptor's status, and from there into its properties
3. Double click the IPv4 item
4. In the IPv4 Properties, click Advanced...
5. In the DNS tab, look for the 'home.network' suffix, and remove it.
6. Hit OK a bunch of times :)

Now you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

For me downloading and reinstalling gem from this page: https://rubygems.org/pages/download solved the Errno::ECONNREFUSED problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on a Mac system, you can try to

`sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`

by edit `search` statement with appending `.local` to a word.

EX:

```
# This file is automatically generated.
#
search network.local
```

NOTE: Above `network` is the domain for this case. You can use any word.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to install premailer and upgrading ruby to current stable version (2.3.0) fixed the issue.

with rvm:

```
rvm install 2.3.0

rvm use 2.3.0

gem install premailer
```

of course, this applies to any gem, not just premailer

Answer (score -3):

Replace the modem Comcast provided with another (Motorola Surfboard SB6141 in this case).

This is an unsatisfying solution, but a solution nonetheless.