# Issues installing CocoaPods on Mac

Tags: macos, cocoapods

I am trying to install CocoaPods, but I get this error:

> Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
>   Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT:
>   Operation timed out - connect(2)
>   (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

When I was searching for solution to my problem mentioned below, I found [this page](https://cs.okstate.edu/~hussach/blog/index.php/p/id/15). That seems more similar to your problem. Hope it works for you! Good luck!

I got a problem as follow:

```
➜  ~  gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) for "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443 (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-0.33.1.gemspec.rz)`enter code here`
```

I'm new here(just know a little about objective-c, know nothing about ruby, gem or rvm). But I found a solution for me. I am not sure whether it works for you or not.

1. go to the OSX network settings, under DNS you'll see the `home.network` line under the Search Domains area
2. click "+" sign, add `home.local`

Or you may try with Starbucks' free wifi.

Reference:
[GitHub](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1001), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583938/gem-install-rails-fails-with-dns-error)