# Error installing CocoaPods on OSX 10.10

Tags: ios, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

I am new to iOS Development and i am trying to install CocoaPods but i am getting
the below Error

```
While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
no such name (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-     attention.network/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-0.33.1.gemspec.rz)
```

So my Question is do i have to install any thing else this to work ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. On Mac OS X, go to System Preferences >> Networks >> Wifi (connected) >> Advanced >> DNS. Under DNS you'll see the `home.network` line under the Search Domains:
2. Click "+", add `home.local`

Source: 
["gem install rails" fails with DNS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583938/gem-install-rails-fails-with-dns-error)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0
5. Uninstall cocoapods : **$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods**
6. Install xcodeproj : **$ sudo gem install xcodeproj**
7. Install cocoapods : **$ sudo gem install cocoapods**
8. Run **pod --version** to verify that it worked