# Getting ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) when I try to install a gem with Ruby ruby 2.0.0p451

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundle

I installed Ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0] using rvm and now I have the list:

```
⇒  rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.6.8 [ x86_64 ]
   jruby-1.7.0 [ x86_64 ]
   jruby-1.7.1 [ x86_64 ]
   mruby-head [ x86_64 ]
   rbx-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-head [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-preview2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

⇒  ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

Now I'm not being able to install any gem and when I do that I get an error:

```
⇒  gem install will_paginate
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.hi.link/quick/Marshal.4.8/will_paginate-3.0.7.gemspec.rz)
```

I'm getting almost the same error whenever I try to install any of the gems.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: seems to be an issue with your router

Comment: are you working on windows ?

Comment: mm you think? but that never happened until I installed this version of ruby. Moreover if I switch to another ruby version with rvm I stop getting the same error, that's why I think it's related to my ruby version.

Comment: No I'm using Mac OS X .

Comment: what is the modem you are using ?

Comment: HUAWEI HiLink (USB). But why do you think it's the case? I just tried to install the same package when I used diff ruby v (2.0.0p353) and it's working fine.

Comment: okay bear with me : go to OSX network settings, under DNS you'll see the `home.network` line under the Search Domains area. After some googling it seems that comcast recently changed this from http://hds1.ma.comcast.net'. change it back, restart and give `gem install rails` a try found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583938/gem-install-rails-fails-with-dns-error

Comment: Working like charm mate, please post the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay bear with me : go to OSX network settings, under DNS you'll see the `home.network` line under the Search Domains area. After some googling it seems that comcast recently changed this from `hds1.ma.comcast.net`;. change it back, restart and give `gem install rails` a try

originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583938/gem-install-rails-fails-with-dns-error)