# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension Bcrypt-Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I am making a rails app and just upgraded to Yosemite, and I think everything broke during that update. Everything was working last night when I checked in all my code to github. I updated my computer last night to Yosemite. Today I ran `gem install bcrypt-ruby` and everything broke. I have;

1. ran `xcodebuild -license`
2. updated bundler
3. ran `brew install rbenv ruby-build rbenv-gem-rehash` to get the latest ruby
4. ran `brew install coreutils`

That did not work though.

**environment:** **OSX Yosemite 10.10**, **rbenv 0.4.0**, **ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0], brew 0.9.5**`

The source of the error is from my rails app:

**gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'pg' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.14"
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', "2.1.0"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
end
```

I got the error when I ran `bundle install`. Here is the full stack trace (all the `/users//` is from taking out the name **;)**

```
 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141027-60319-1lss4fm.rb extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:51:21: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:61:21: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:64:23: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:68:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:29:21: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:194,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1567,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/missing.h:23:45: error: math.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:36:23: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:40:22: error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:43,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/st.h:140: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
In file included from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568,
                 from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:326: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:416: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:416: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:416: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:416: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:416: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:417: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:417: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:417: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:417: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:418: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:514: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘mode_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:593: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘pid_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:607: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:608: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork_err’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:610: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_waitpid’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:611: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:612: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:613: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn_err’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:615: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:728: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:851: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:852: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
bcrypt_ext.c: In function ‘bc_salt’:
bcrypt_ext.c:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users//ticket_tracker/vendor/bundle/gems/bcrypt-3.1.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users//ticket_tracker/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If anyone has had some experience updated OSX, Rbenv, Ruby etc and can give me some pointers, that would be much appreciated. I can also post more code/environment set up if needed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem which I solved by re-installing the XCode command line developer tools :

```
xcode-select --install
bundle install
```

Comment: For some reason that's what I thought I solved with `xcode -license`. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: It seems like every new install or update of xcode requires reinstall of command line tools.

Comment: Slightly different take, I had the same error, tried xcodebuild -license and got an error saying needing to use sudo, so 'sudo xcodebuild -license' and it worked. I'm still on Mavericks but have got Yosemite downloaded to install, so not sure if that's impacting things.

Comment: Getting a popup that says `Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.`. Any idea if thats a temporary thing?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and same issue come to me? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Only a combination of actions helped me to solve the issue.
Here is my sequence

1)

```
xcode-select --install
bundle install
```

2)

```
brew update
brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
```

3) Switched from ruby 2.1.4 to 2.1.5

```
rbenv install 2.1.5   
rbenv global 2.1.5
rbenv shell 2.1.5
rbenv rehash
gem install bundler
bundle
```

4) (optional) in case you had issue with installing nokogiri

```
brew install libxml2
bundle config build.nokogiri "--use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2"
bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to OS X Yosemite and trying to run some rails apps I came across some other problems;

Due to some apple insanity after installing Xcode gcc does not compile programs like any other gcc compiler - instead it asks you to read and agree to the license agreement - which is a bloody cheek considering it is gcc.  Try

```
gcc --version
```

then page through the license crap and type agree at the end then it should act as a normal gcc compiler.

However that still may not work as the bundled version of gcc (4.2.1) is too old for libv8 (4.4 was required) so instead you need to install a later version of gcc using macports.  Visit http://www.macports.org/install.php.  Once macports is installed type

```
sudo port install gcc48 +universal 
sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc48
hash gcc
gcc --version
```

and you should see

```
gcc (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.4_0+universal) 4.8.4
```

as of 3/2/2015 gcc4.8 has had 4 bug fix releases and gcc4.9 has had 2 so take your pick.

Now that you have a more up to date gcc compiler the next hurdle is getting therubyracer to build.  Gcc4.8 on darwin does not recognise -rdynamic option so therubyracer will not build.

I have forked therubyracer and modified extconf.rb to twiddle the compiler options - you can use it from github.  To do so change your Gemfile like so

```
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes 
platforms :ruby do
  if RUBY_PLATFORM=~ /darwin/ 
    gem 'therubyracer', :git => 'https://github.com/damianham/therubyracer.git'
  else
    gem 'therubyracer', '0.12.1' 
  end
end
```

Comment: Please don't install both homebrew and macports.  You will run in to some bizarre conflict and it will be a nightmare to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ruby v 2.2.2, this helped me when I received this ERROR:

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension Bcrypt-Ruby

```
xcode-select --install 
brew update
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

If xcode-select --install fails make sure you have accepted the license

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is anyone out there still struggling and it isn't obvious, I would recommend that you install XCode.  I've done two OSX 10.10 upgrades and they both required XCode to solve this issue.