# Connection Refused RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently attempting to install a gem `gem install micromidi`. Whenever I run it from terminal I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'micromidi' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I'm not behind a proxy and I have an internet connection. I've installed gems before and have never had a problem. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: What do you get with `gem install micromidi --debug --backtrace --verbose`?

Comment: What do you want specifically? The entire stacktrace? It's too large to post in entirety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been a few recent merges of commits regarding ssl and mentioning **"fastly"**, like this search of the repo: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/search?o=desc&q=fastly&s=created&type=Issues

Also, `2.6.3 / 2016-04-05 […] New fastly cert. Pull request #1548 by David Radcliffe` see: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/ccb9c3300c063f5b5656669972d24a10ef8afbf5/History.txt#L63

---

**ANSWER**

I recommend manually updating to ***RubyGems v2.6.6 - June 22, 2016*** via https://rubygems.org/pages/download:

> If you don't have any RubyGems installed, there is still the pre-gem
>   approach to getting software, doing it manually:
>
> 1. Download from above
> 2. Unpack into a directory and `cd` there
> 3. Install with: `ruby setup.rb` (you may need admin/root privilege)

---

**RESOURCES**

If the above doesn't resolve the issue, here are some additional resources:

- [**Comcast ISP**] issue: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1001
- [**OS X**] Helpful Stack Overflow question: ["gem install rails" fails with DNS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583938/gem-install-rails-fails-with-dns-error)
- [**Windows**] *Workaround RubyGems' SSL errors on Ruby for Windows (RubyInstaller)*, via https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue:

> **Step 1: Obtain the new trust certificate**
>
> […]
>
> We need to download AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem[ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem ]
>
> Use the above link and place/save this file somewhere you can later
>   find easily (eg. your Desktop).
>
> **IMPORTANT:** File must have `.pem` as extension. Browsers like Chrome will
>   try to save it as plain text file. Ensure you change the filename to
>   have `.pem` in it after you have downloaded it.
>
> **Step 2: Locate RubyGems certificate directory in your installation**
>
> In order for us copy this file, we need to know where to put it.
>
> Depending on where you installed Ruby, the directory will be
>   different.
>
> Take for example the default installation of Ruby 2.1.5, placed in
>   `C:\Ruby21`
>
> Open a Command Prompt and type in:
>
> ```
> C:\>gem which ruby gems
> C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
> ```
>
> Now, let's locate that directory. From within the same window, 
>   enter the path part up to the file extension, but using 
>   backslashes instead:
>
> ```
> C:\>start C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems
> ```
>
> This will open a Explorer
>   window inside the directory we indicated.
>
> **Step 3: Copy new trust certificate**
>
> Now, locate `ssl_certs` directory and copy the `.pem` file we obtained
>   from previous step inside.
>
> It will be listed with other files like `GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem`.